# how does this square model not follow the 4 incidence axioms of geometry?

Tags: geometry, logic, euclidean-geometry

[image: square image]

I'm having trouble understanding how this square fails the four incidence axioms of geometry for reference:

- Axiom 1: there exist at least three distinct non-collinear points
- Axiom 2: given any two distinct points, there is at least one line that contains both of them
- Axiom 3: given any two distinct points, there is at most one line that contains both of them
- Axiom 4: given any line, there are at least two distinct points that lie on it

The interpretation of the square is that *point* means any of the vertices of a square, *line* means any of the sides of that square, and *lies on* means the point is one of the endpoints of the side

From my understanding the image satisfies all four axioms.
Three points do not share a line, with each two points there is a single unique line, and for every line there are two points so how does the square model fail?

Comment: Axiom 2 fails.  What line contains opposite vertices of the square?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your square fails to satisfy Axiom 2, as there is no line which contains opposite vertices of the square.  However, the following figure seems to satisfy all four axioms:

[image]

This figure is composed of four points and six lines.  *No* three of the points are collinear (thus there exist three non-collinear points—Axiom 1 is satisfied), there is exactly one line containing any pair of points (thus Axioms 2 and 3 are satisfied), and each line contains exactly two points (satisfying Axiom 4).

---

Note that the example above is essentially the complete graph on four vertices.  This generalizes:  given a set of $n$ vertices, the complete graph on those $n$ vertices will satisfy the axioms given.  On the other hand, this is not a unique arrangement.  For example, the [Fano plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane) (shown below) is a space with 7 points which is *not* equivalent to the complete graph on 7 vertices.

[image: Fano plane]

Comment: so to satisfy axiom 2 the shape has to connect every two points together? so if were a pentagon each vertex would have 4 lines? (making a star)

Comment: To satisfy Axiom 2, each pair of points must be contained in a line, yes.  But there are other ways of satisfying the hypotheses (though I think not with just four points, maybe).

Comment: thanks i get it now